# Errors while accessing the EDB

Tags: exchange, edb

My Exchange Server is delivering outgoing mails without attachments. Strange to my surprise I am also encountering ESE (Extensible Storage Engine) errors while accessing the EDB (Exchange Server Database) file. Why it is so and how to overcome from such issue?

Comment: Explain what you mean by the statement: "I am also encountering ESE (Extensible Storage Engine) errors while accessing the EDB (Exchange Server Database) file.". Do you mean you're seeing warnings and/or errors in the event log? How are you accessing the EDB file when you see these errors? What are the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem you are witnessing indicates about the corruption of Exchange Server database. You need to go for Exchange Server Recovery to get your database repaired, if an updated and complete backup is not in place. However, the most probable reasons for facing such problems could be –

1. Transactions are not committed to the hard drive by Disk Caching and
   the Exchange Server is crashed.
2. List item In the process of restoring database wrong log files were replayed.

**To overcome from such issue, you just got to go through the steps:**

1. If your hard drive has logical problems, run ChkDsk utility to detect
   and fix hard drive related errors.
2. In case of database corruption and other database related issues,
   run DBCC CHECKDB.

By following these steps you would be able to fix the corruption issue quite easily. If not fix then you can use the professional software. For more detail http://exchangeserver.tumblr.com/ and

**some professional tools**

http://www.nucleustechnologies.com/Exchange-Server-Data-Recovery.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that for the error handling you should try this [thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg269184%28v=exchg.10%29.aspx). And if your Exchange database is corrupt then you can try one of many third-party tools to repair your EDB files.